# Is it safe to use UUIDs as keys in Google Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I've read that when setting custom keys in Google Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode, it's important to [avoid using monotonically increasing IDs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices#keys) as these could lead to hotspots.

Allowing Google to generate the IDs would avoid this problem.

However, I would like to set my own IDs by generating a UUID for each entity. Is this approach likely to lead to the hotspotting problems described in the article? Or would the entropy in a UUID mean that entities are likely to be well distributed throughout the keyspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a standard random [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), it will have more than enough entropy.